# C++17 optional tree, error: invalid use of incomplete type

Tags: c++, templates, std, option-type, c++17

When I compile a binary tree containing optional types:

```
#include <optional>

class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    int value;
    std::optional<BinaryTree> left,right;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

via

```
g++ -std=c++17 -Wfatal-errors main.cpp
```

I face with this error

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/move.h:54:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_pair.h:59,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/utility:70,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7/optional:36,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits: In instantiation of ‘struct std::is_trivially_copy_constructible<BinaryTree>’:
/usr/include/c++/7/optional:103:8:   required from ‘class std::_Optional_base<BinaryTree>’
/usr/include/c++/7/optional:451:11:   required from ‘class std::optional<BinaryTree>’
main.cpp:8:28:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/type_traits:1409:12: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class BinaryTree’
     struct is_trivially_copy_constructible
            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

How should I fix this error?

Comment: If you weren't using `std::optional`, how would you declare `left` and `right`?

Comment: @DeiDei, I would still declare them but by pointers.

Comment: The compiler needs to determine the size of `left` which depends on the [complete] definition of `BinaryTree`. Essentially, you cannot embed an object of a class into an object of the same class. Use, e.g., `std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree>` instead.

Comment: You would use pointers, because `BinaryTree` is still an incomplete type at that point. The error is the same. `std::optional` is not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Optional contains the complete instance of the type when it is engaged.

Storing two instances of a type within an instance of the type is impossible; it requires 2<=1.

Consider using a unique pointer to the type instead of an optional.

If you want to be able to copy the tree then you have to write a value pointer.  Value pointer is a pointer that knows how to deep copy itself.

Answer (score 0):

@Yakk's answer is correct.

As @Dietmar Kühl points out, `std::unique_ptr` is what you want for nullable not-in-place storage:

```
#include <memory>

class BinaryTree
{
public:
    BinaryTree();
    int value;
    std::unique_ptr<BinaryTree> left,right;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You want to use a BinaryTree pointer instead of actual BinaryTree member, because the type is incomplete. Replace

```
std::optional<BinaryTree> left,right;
```

with

```
std::optional<BinaryTree*> left,right;
```

Comment: Then why not `BinaryTree* left,right` when the type is nullable?